# How to make this greyscale effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture

I don't know if this a right place to ask, but... basically, I want to make my photos look like photos scanned from old newspaper with flat colors and scratches. Here is few examples what I mean:

[image: Brazilian Field]

[image: Brazilian Spider]

[image: hennepin-bridge-belly]

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try Posterize and Add Scratches, in that order?

Comment: @RadLexus hi yes, I try it, I feel I'm close. Any tip to reduce the noise?

Comment: this is the right place to ask. Would be better if you [edit your question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/75890/edit) to include your own results as well so we can help you where you are stuck

Answer (score 1):

- Decrease Saturation if image is colored.
- Adjust the lightness and curve adjustments to set the contrast
- Posterize the image in a new layer
- Select the *Shades of grey* [:P] and smooth-en the selection and paint in the selection in a new layer.
- Add another layer of curve adjustment for finishing touch.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here what you can do in photoshop -

1.Convert the image you want the effect on to black and white

2.go to Filter > Artistic > use the filter "colored pencil"

[image]